# Backup specific tables from mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql

I want backup specific tables from `mysql` database using `java`.
I take successfully backup of database using it. Here database name is art_school and tables are branch, class, employee.

```
batchCommand=mysqldump -h localhost --port 3306 -u root  --add-drop-database -B art_school -r G:\Backup\Backup20150820175317.sql
```

Its execute from `java` as well as cmd.

But for backup specific tables,

```
batchcommand=mysqldump -h localhost --port 3306 -u root art_school branch class employee > G:\Backup\BT20150820175319.sql
```

Its execute on cmd but not from java code.

Comment: Show us the java code.

Answer (score 0):

The `>` sign to write something to a file works only in the command line. In Java you'll have to read the output of the command yourself:

```
Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping localhost");
InputStream is = exec.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String line=br.readLine(); line!=null; line=br.readLine()) {
    builder.append(line);
    builder.append('\n');
}
String text = builder.toString();
System.out.println(text);
```

You can then write those contends to a File with Java.

---

Alternatively you can put your commands in a Batch-File (.bat) and run that Batch-File from Java.

Comment: Its not create backup file as well as not backup data